# Distribution of Quantum Measurement Uncertainties (what Exactly does the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle tell us)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

In quantum mechanics, one of the first results students (and random people with an interest in physics) are exposed to is the Heisenberg Incertainty Principle. Informally, this principle expresses the product of the uncertainties of certain pairs of properties must be greater than some fixed value. Essentially, the "knowabilities" of certain pairs of properties of a quantum particle are linked such that certainty in one gives rise to uncertainty in another. Typically, the properties position and momentum are given as an example, so I will use those for the remainder of this question.

I will use $x$ and $\Delta x$ for position and uncertainty in position and $p$ and $\Delta p$ for momentum and uncertainty in momentum, all respectively.

My question is this:

If I make a measurement, and say I know the measurement has uncertainty $\Delta x$, what distribution should I expect "actual" position to follow. I know $\Delta x$ and let's say I know $\Delta p$ as well. These are *numbers*, they don't describe a physical state without some context. Are $\Delta x$ and $\Delta p$ the bounds of a uniform distribution describing the possible values of $x$ and $p$? Are they the variance of a normal distribution? Are they the variance (or some other property) of a distribution whose shape is determined by the quantum state of the particles interacting during the observation?

I have found some resources (like this one https://opentextbc.ca/universityphysicsv3openstax/chapter/the-heisenberg-uncertainty-principle/) that reference this but don't ever give an explicit answer. I also know that the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle is a special case of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, which I plan to explore as an avenue to answering this question for myself.

Comment: I don't know you math level, but for instance the square of the wave function gives you the probability on x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are they the variance of a distribution whose shape is determined by the quantum state of the particles interacting during the observation?

Yes.

Comment: Nice, a straight answer. I love it. Any good resources for deriving the distribution?

Comment: @MichaelNew The square of the norm of the wavefunction in position space is the probability distribution for position. $\Delta x$ is the variance of this distribution. The square of the norm of the wavefunction in momentum space is the probability distribution for momentum. $\Delta p$ is the variance of this distribution.  There's some discussion on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Wave_mechanics_interpretation)

Comment: Ah, I think there's been a disconnect. I'm interested in the shape of the wave function *the moment after observation*. I'm comfortable in general with the Born rule and the Schrodinger equation and how they can be used to make predictions regarding where a particle will be observed, but I'm curious what the distribution looks like the moment after "collapse", when the Uncertainty Principle is pushed to its limit in some sense. I'd say you answered half of my question so far, but I'm curious if the distribution after collapse depends on the distribution before collapse.

Comment: @MichaelNew It's not really a different situation. If you make a perfect measurement of position, then the wavefunction becomes a delta function in position space, so the momentum space wavefunction is a constant. That's obviously a singular situation. In practice you will measure position with some uncertainty, so you could model the position space wavefunction as a Gaussian with variance given by your experimental error. There's not a single prescription that tells you what the wavefunction is after a measurement, it depends on your measurement.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to assume that a particle being measured has a definite position and momentum and that Δx and Δp represent an uncertainty in the result of the measurement. That is a misleading view. The uncertainty relation expresses the fact that a particle cannot posses a definite momentum and position simultaneously. This follows directly from the properties of waves. A pure sine wave (which is a mathematical abstraction) has a perfectly defined frequency but no location- it is spread throughout space.  A localised wave (ie one whose amplitude tails off to zero over some finite space) does not have a single frequency (although it might have a dominant one)- instead it is a superposition of many overtones. The more localised the wave, the more the overtones are present in the mix. The uncertainty relation simply represents that fact- that the narrower the spatial spread of the wave, the more the overtones are present in it, while conversely the more the overtones drop out to reveal a dominant fundamental frequency the more the wave must be spread through space.

So, a wave cannot have a well-defined position without having a wide spread of frequencies (ie momentum values), and it cannot have a well-defined frequency (ie momentum) without being widely spread through space.

Comment: I'm fairly comfortable with the concepts you are describing, but I lack the verbiage to make my question clear and concise without fudging that detail. I'd argue that my question is really phrased in a Bohmian way, but even with a Copenhagen interpretation I'd say there's an argument to be made based on the discrete, localized nature of particles *when observed* that there is some deeper sense of locality that does belong to the particle than just its wave function, although then we get into a philosophical debate about the measurement problem.

Comment: I think 'measurement problem' is a misnomer, as it suggests there is something special about the act of measuring. A measurement performed on a particle is simply a physical interaction, no different to any other sort that can be experienced by a particle. Typically it is the result of a local electromagnetic interaction between the particle being observed and particles that make up the detecting part of the apparatus. We talk about the particle's wave function after measurement, but that in itself includes an implicit simplification...

Comment: ...which is that we take the wave function to be a combination of energy states associated with a Hamiltonian in which the particle exists in some potential field- which is a classical simplification. The particle and the particles that make-up the detecting part of the apparatus will interact quantum mechanically, which means they will have a multi-particle wave function and a many-body interaction- representing the latter as a single-body approximation in which the particle being measured experiences the averaged out potential due to the others is a simplification.